# Cast and convert an oracle sql column

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi i have a table with a column name as emp id's in ORACLE SQL

Like `12` , `243` ,`55457` etc.
I want to cast it like in *15* digits to achieve a uniform pattern as below :

```
000000000000012
000000000000243
000000000055457
```

Any function to achieve the same ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`lpad`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_2017.htm#OLADM593) function pads the left side of a string to a certain length with filler text:

```
select lpad(col, 15, '0')
```